# Is there a shorthand for type variable 'm forSome { type m[O] <: UpperBound[O] }` in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, existential-type, higher-kinded-types

Problem:

```
trait UpperBound[O]
trait High[F[O] <: UpperBound[O]]

def canEqual(that :Any) = that.isInstanceOf[High[_]]

def high(h :High[_]) = ???
```

Does not compile, because scalac sees the `_` type instead of a type constructor it expects. How to fix it, ideally without writing a novel?

Original question (before edits in reply to Dmytro's answer) had:

```
def canEqual(that :Any) = that.isInstanceOf[High[m forSome { type m[O] <: UpperBound[O] }]]

def high(h :High[m forSome { type m[O] <: UpperBound[O] }] = ???
```

Is there a shorter way of writing the above two methods by using some wildcard expression?
Simply using `_` in `High`'s type parameter position doesn't work as the kind doesn't match, and `_[_]` is not even a valid type expression.

Comment: regarding your updated question do you mean just `def high(h: High[F] forSome {type F[O] <: UpperBound[O] }) = ???`?

Comment: Interesting. I was never aware there is a difference between what I wrote in the original question and your snippet here. I need to reread SLS more carefully, because I can't see at all where it comes from.

Comment: Well, I guess it's clear that `List[X[A]] forSome { type A }` and `List[X[A] forSome { type A }]` are different. The former consists of elements having types `X[A]`, where `A` is arbitrary but the same for all elements. The latter consists of elements having types `X[A]`, where `A` is arbitrary and can be different for different elements.

Comment: Yeah, now that you mention it, it is kind of obvious. In my defense, I used it in the context of a single value, so the natural language semantics where the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you make existential quantization outside `High` then it's just

  ```
  type T = High[F] forSome { type F[O] <: UpperBound[O] }

  def canEqual(that: Any) = that.isInstanceOf[T]

  def high(h: T) = ???
  ```
- If you make existential quantization inside `High` then since

  ```
  implicitly[(n forSome { type n <: Upper}) =:= Upper]
  implicitly[(m[O1] forSome { type m[O] <: UpperBound[O]}) =:= UpperBound[O1]]
  ```

  (and vice versa) it's just `High[UpperBound]`

  ```
  implicitly[High[m forSome { type m[O] <: UpperBound[O] }] =:= High[UpperBound]]

  def canEqual(that: Any) = that.isInstanceOf[High[UpperBound]]

  def high(h: High[UpperBound]) = ???
  ```

  > An existential type  `forSome {  }` where  contains a clause type `[tps]>:<:` is equivalent to the type `′ forSome {  }` where `′` results from  by replacing every covariant occurrence of  in  by  and by replacing every contravariant occurrence of  in  by .

  https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#simplification-rules

Comment: `High` in the example is invariant regarding its type parameter, hence substitution doesn't apply. Given `LowerBound[O] extends UpperBound[O]`, `High[LowerBound]` is not a subtype of `High[UpperBound]`.

Comment: Ok, evidently what I wrote is not what I meant, sorry! I was interested in an 'erased' form of `High[_]` which would not trigger warnings when used in `isInstanceOf`/pattern matching *and* will be the super type of any instance of `High`. I am not sure how to refrase that, but I'll try.

Comment: @Turin Yeah, regarding your first comment, variance of `High` is not significant, significant is that occurence of `m` in `m[O1]` is covariant, that's why `(m[O1] forSome { type m[O] <: UpperBound[O]}) =:= UpperBound[O1]` for all `O1`.

Comment: Still, with `trait Lower[O] exteds UpperBound[O]`, the code `high(new High[Lower])` does not compile, and that's a bit surprising to me. Going to SLS to read that section again, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: @Turin Looks like some issue with type inference. For `type T = High[F] forSome {type F[O] <: UpperBound[O] }` `def high(h: T) = ???`: `implicitly[High[Lower] <:< T]` compiles, `new High[Lower] {} : High[Lower]` compiles, `new High[Lower] {} : T` doesn't compile, `high(new High[Lower] {})` doesn't compile, `high(new High[Lower] {} : High[Lower])` compiles, `high(new High[Lower] {} : T)` doesn't compile, `high((new High[Lower] {} : High[Lower]) : T)` compiles. Scala 2.13.1.