# Self-type annotation for class with higher kinded type

Tags: scala, existential-type, higher-kinded-types, self-type

Given:

```
abstract class Databases[F[_]]
```

How can I make this trait work:

```
// Marker trait signalling the database plugin supports StaticRoles
trait StaticRoles { this: Databases[_] => }
```

I want to ensure `StaticRoles` is only mixed-in in classes that also extend `Databases`, however I don't care about the concrete value of the type parameter `F`.

The code returns:

```
error: _$1 takes no type parameters, expected: one
```

Which is fair, however it returns the same error for:

```
trait StaticRoles { this: Databases[_[_]] => }
```

I've also tried:

```
trait StaticRoles { this: Databases[({type T[X[_]]})#T] => }
```

Which gives the error:

```
error: kinds of the type arguments (AnyRef{type T[X[_]]}#T) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type F) in class Databases.
       AnyRef{type T[X[_]]}#T's type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters:
       type X has one type parameter, but type _ has none
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct one is

```
trait StaticRoles { this: (Databases[F] forSome { type F[_] }) => }
```

[Is there a shorthand for type variable 'm forSome { type m[O] <: UpperBound[O] }` in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041172/is-there-a-shorthand-for-type-variable-m-forsome-type-mo-upperboundo)

Not every existential type is expressible with underscores or (in this case) allowed to be expressed with underscores.

There is also

```
trait StaticRoles { this: Databases[F forSome { type F[_] }] => }
```

different from the former but the same as

```
trait StaticRoles { this: Databases[Any] => }
```

since

```
implicitly[(Databases[F forSome { type F[_] }]) =:= Databases[Any]]
```

(`Any` is actually poly-kinded).

`Databases[Any]` is a subtype of `Databases[F] forSome { type F[_] }`

```
implicitly[Databases[Any] <:< (Databases[F] forSome { type F[_] })]
```

With type projections (`#`) correct is

```
trait StaticRoles { this: Databases[({ type F[_] })#F] => }
```

`Databases[({ type F[_] })#F]` is also a subtype of `Databases[F] forSome { type F[_] }` (uncomparable with `Databases[Any]` for invariant  `Databases`).

Among these three types `Databases[F] forSome { type F[_] }`, `Databases[Any]`, and `Databases[({ type F[_] })#F]` only the first one works with

```
trait IO[_]

class Abc extends Databases[IO] with StaticRoles // compiles

//class Abc1 extends StaticRoles // doesn't compile
```

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes, only these two are.

Comment: Nice! I somehow entirely missed [this one](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7594). Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to do the version with type projections using the kind projector?

Comment: @SimãoMartins No. Kind projector simplifies type lambdas, there is no type lambda here.

Comment: @SimãoMartins Actually neither type projection version nor `Databases[Any]` works with self-type and mixin as intended. Only `forSome` does. See example with class `Abc` in update of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define as following:

```
  abstract class Databases[F[_]]

  trait StaticRoles[F[_]] { this: Databases[F] =>

    def abc: String
  }

  class Abc extends Databases[IO] with StaticRoles[IO] {
    override def abc: String = ???
  }
```

Note: If you remove `Databases[IO]` and just just define like this

```
class Abc extends StaticRoles[IO] {...}
```

This won't compile. I think this is what you want to achieve